# Use variables inside variable file in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've an Ansible vars_file like:

```
jmeter:
  version: "5.3"
  name: "apache-jmeter-{{ jmeter.version }}"
  archive: "{{ jmeter.name }}.zip"
  url: "https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/{{ jmeter.archive }}"
```

Is it the way to go? I'm getting error. Anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten that, as `jmeter` is not defined yet when you are trying to use it.

```
jmeter_version: "5.3"
jmeter_name: "apache-jmeter-{{ jmeter_version }}"
jmeter_archive: "{{ jmeter_name }}.zip"
jmeter_url: "https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/{{ jmeter_archive }}"
```